# Why does parent view grow when child image has height 50%?

Tags: react-native, layout

TLDR: I'd expect a parent view to only be as big as required to hold its children (unless it's given some explicit style instructions about what size to be or what margins/padding to add).  I have a View holding an Image and this works fine in general, but if I give the Image a style with `height: '50%';` the View displays at about 3x the height of the Image.

What's going on?

Here's a screenshot without the image height explicitly set:

[image]

And here's one where the height is set at 50%:

[image]

Here's the code:

App.tsx:

```
const App = () => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
        <LinearGradient colors={['#4B9E94', '#B868F8']} style={{...styles.linearGradient}}>
          <FancyHeader ...unimportant props />
          <BreadcrumbBar ...unimportant props />
          <ImagePane image={placeholder_sm} />
        </LinearGradient>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
};
```

ImagePane.tsx

```
const style = StyleSheet.create({
    semitransparentPane: {
        backgroundColor: semiTransparentWhite,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0,
    },
    image: {
        height: '50%',
    }
});

type Props = {
    image: ImageSourcePropType;
}

const ImagePane: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {

    return (
        <View style={style.semitransparentPane}>
            <Image source={props.image} style={style.image} resizeMode={'contain'} resizeMethod={'scale'} />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to set the parent view to a preferred height, you must set the height of the view as well.

`semitransparentPane: { backgroundColor: semiTransparentWhite, justifyContent: 'center', alignContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', padding: 0, margin: 0, height:100, width:'100%' },`

and play with the value of height